# How to change font of matlab console in windows

Tags: matlab

I like to run matlab in console mode without `JVM`. So basically I run this command:

```
matlab /nojvm
```

It looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is change this font. And maybe the colors. What would be best is that if I could make it like the shell of Cygwin minty

[image]

However, I can't seem to find any way to do this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you start Matlab without the Java Virtual Machine, you don't get its standard GUI which is implemented in Java, but Matlab runs in console mode, meaning it uses the keyboard input / screen output routines provided by the shell it is started from. Under a Unix-like system, nowadays this is usually a terminal emulator running under X, and the font used can be changed by using the settings of that terminal emulator. I have to admit I haven't ever done this under Windows, but I think you'd start Matlab from the Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe), and you could change font settings in the Command Prompt program (try right-click, or system menu).

However, the screen shot you show doesn't have the title "Command Prompt", but "MATLAB Command Window". To me that looks like you weren't successful using that option, but you still have the standard MATLAB Java GUI. Moreover, a look at the [command line options of Matlab under Windows](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html) shows a) that all options start with a "-", not a "/", and b) that there is no option "nojvm", at least in 2013b. My guess is that Matlab simply ignored the option "/nojvm".

You can change the font used in the Matlab Command Window in the preferences. Since you don't seem to have the menu, type `preferences` into the command window.

Comment: I am using matlab 2011a. Even when I run the command `matlab /nojvm` from a `cmd`, it opens a new white console as shown in the picture. And running `preferences` gives this error `Preferences is not supported because Java is not currently available.`. So I guess matlab implemented there own console for nojvm use.

Comment: Yes, it looks like that, strange... The only thing I can think of then would be to find the settings of that special console; I'd try right-click into the window or try system menu (last time I checked, Alt-Space). But since this seems like a hack, I guess its possible that you cannot customize it. Stupidly, 2011b documentation is not accessible online without associated license. – What happens if you start matlab from the Cygwin window? Did you try `matlab -help`, maybe there is a special option to let Matlab run in a cmd window.